# Create kind of retail mode Android

Tags: android, video, screensaver

I want to create a kind of "retail mode" to display a video on the phone screen when it is locked, as in stores. It's a bit like a screen saver. I don't know how to do it. I tried to put my differents phones into Retail Mode but  I wanna be able to change the video that is played. Moreover, I didn't manage to put all the phones into Retail Mode.

Can someone help me please ?
Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `Activity` that is shown above the lock screen like this:

```java
public class LockScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        makeActivityShownOnLock();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lock_screen);
    }

    private void makeActivityShownOnLock() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
            setShowWhenLocked(true);
            setTurnScreenOn(true);
        }
        else {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        }
    }
```

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".activity.LockScreenActivity"
    android:showOnLockScreen="true"
    android:showWhenLocked="true" />
```

This way, the `Activity` will persist even if You turn the screen off and on.

As far as I know, some phones require additional permissions to show activities on lock sreen (like Xiaomi), so take that into account.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I forgot to mention that I don't know how to code an app on android....